# Proving that $f'(x)\geq 0$ for a monotonic increasing function.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a non-empty interval and $f:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function.

I want to prove that if $f$ is a monotonic increasing function, then $f'(x)\geq 0$.

Let $c\in I$. Then if $x<c$, $f(x)<f(c)$ and if $c<x$, $f(c)<f(x)$.
So either way, $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\geq 0$, for all $x\in I\ \backslash \{c\}$. Now if we take limits in both sides, we see that $f'(x)\geq 0$, for all $x\in I\ \backslash \{c\}$. But I have to prove this also for $x=c$. How can I do this?

Comment: I like to consider contrapositives. In this case that means to take a point $c$ where  $f'(c)<0$, and show that the function cannot be monotonic increasing. I think that's easier.

Comment: Taking limits as $x\to c$ yields $f'(c)$ so $f'(c)\geqslant 0$.

Comment: You have proved that $f'(c) \ge 0$, the $x$ is a 'temporary variable'.

Comment: You can't prove $\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c} > 0$ for $x = c$, since the expression is undefined there. However, you can take a limit as $x \to c$, and since the expression is always positive, the limit must be greater than or equal to $0$.